# Android Development RSS Feed does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, compiler-errors, rss

I am reading Head First Android Development Book, it's a great book, but I am in the second Chapter(Chapter 2) and I can't get this RSS app working. So, basically, this is not supposed to be the final version but all it should do so far is just desplay the app as empty. Sounds stupid, but it shouldn't display anything yet becasue I must set up some permissions for the app in order to allow the app to connect to the internet and download the RSS informations. I am working with 4 different files for this app(but obviously, there are more files in the project).

I made a Google Docs Folder so everyone can see it and download it. I used Eclipse.

Please help me this is a greap book but I cannot turn to the next chapter until I find a solution.

Once again, this is not supposed to be the final version, the app should be seen as empty because I need to set up some permissions for it. It gives me errors, please HELP me!!!

The main problem I have is this line, it says "iotdHandler cannot be resolved". I have no idea why the book says I should not capitalize this word I gues I should like "IotdHandler" but it still gives me errors. I followed everything from the book. Help me!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IotdHandler handler = new IotdHandler();
    handler.processFeed();
    resetDisplay(iotdHandler.getTitle(), iotdHandler.getDate(), iotdHandler.getImage(), iotdHandler.getDescription());
}
```

This code was from the mainActivity.java file

Please Help Me, it's driving me crazy!!!

Thanks

Comment: Forgot the RSS source. http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss

Answer (score 0):

Hey man i feel your pain I spent two days on that chapter figuring out solutions for the bugs.
Fist and foremost this is not a finish version of the book it is plagued with errors so don't feel bad and keep that in mind.

**strong text** 
Here are the solutions to your problems.

On mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.nasadailyimage;

import android.iotdHandler;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IotdHandler handler = new IotdHandler(); //create handler
    handler.processFeed(); //start parsing
    resetDisplay(iotdHandler.getTitle(), iotdHandler.getDate(),
            iotdHandler.getImage(), iotdHandler.getDescription());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void resetDisplay(String title, String date, String imageUrl, String description)
{
    TextView titleView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
    titleView.setText(title);

    TextView dateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageDate);
    dateView.setText(date);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
    Bitmap image = null;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    TextView descriptionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageDescription);
    descriptionView.setText(description);

}
```

}

Second: You need to create a file called **IotdHandler.java** in your src folder.
and in this file you need to create the following Getter Methods

```
package android;

public class iotdHandler {

public static String getDate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public static String getTitle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public static String getImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public static String getDescription() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

All my Best

Comment: please check your  answer again.Don`t waste  others time

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the head first writer is a bit incoherent in terms of **object naming**.

1. what object is declared is not used. (`IotdHandler made, iotdHandler`
   used.) java and consequently **android** are case-sensitive.
2. sometimes the `signature parameter of methods` are different than that
   of the declared methods. like it should be (**String, String, Bitmap,
   StringBuffer**), but the caller uses (**String, String, String, String**).

I would suggest you to read the **Wrox or Apress android books** for doing programming exercises and then go for `HeadFirst coding ideas to have robust code`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is rather old but perhaps my answer will help the next person that might find themselves here, especially since there is no accepted answer.

As stated, this book is full of errors and can make a newbie to android and java, like me, a bit crazy. After a few days of googling and reading I have managed to get this working, so here goes.

I'm not sure what version of android the OP was using, but I think one of the problems with the code in the book is the addition from Honeycomb (3.x) and above versions, of not allowing potentially expensive operations on the UI thread. Read more about it:

```
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html
```

For this problem, you need to run the potentially expensive operation on a separate thread using ASyncTask.

Please note in the code that catches exceptions, I just printed the exception error to the titleView TextView to make it easier to figure out what the problems were.

After running the code in the AsyncTask had completed, then update the display.

The startElement method also seemed to be incorrect because if you view the RSS feed details in the XML Editor, the URL needed for the image is under "enclosure".

My code below, please leave a comment with any questions; and please note I am pretty much a beginner as well, so there might very well be a better way of doing this.

```
package neill.nasadailyimage;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;

import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NasaDailyImage extends ActionBarActivity
{
    IotdHandler handler = new IotdHandler(); // Create handler

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nasa_daily_image);

        handler.processFeed();     
    }

    public void ResetDisplay() {

         String title = handler.getTitle();
         String date = handler.getDate();
         String description = handler.getDescription().toString();

         resetDisplay(title, date, handler.getImage(), description);
    }

    private void resetDisplay(String title, String date, Bitmap image, String description)
    {
        try {

            TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
            titleView.setText(title);

            TextView dateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageDate);
            dateView.setText(date);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

            TextView descriptionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageDescription);
            descriptionView.setText(description);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
                titleView.setText(e.toString());
            }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nasa_daily_image, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class IotdHandler extends DefaultHandler
    {
        private String url = "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss";

        private boolean inTitle = false;
        private boolean inDescription = false;
        private boolean inItem = false;
        private boolean inDate = false;

        private Bitmap image = null;
        private String title = null;
        private String date = null;
        private StringBuffer description = new StringBuffer();

        public XMLReader reader = null;

        private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
        {
            try 
            {   
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();

                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                input.close();

                return bitmap;

            } 
            catch (IOException ioe) 
            { 
                TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
                titleView.setText(ioe.toString());

                return null;
            }
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
        {
               if (localName.equals("enclosure")) {
                   image = getBitmap(attributes.getValue("url").toString());
               }

               if (localName.startsWith("item")) { inItem = true; } 
               else 
               {                  
                   if (inItem) {
                       if (localName.equals("title")) { inTitle = true; } 
                       else {   inTitle = false; }

                       if (localName.equals("description")) { inDescription = true; } 
                       else { inDescription = false; }

                       if (localName.equals("pubDate")) { inDate = true; } 
                       else { inDate = false; }
                   }
               }        
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        {
                 String chars = (new String(ch).substring(start, start + length));

                 if (inTitle && title == null) { title = chars; }

                 if (inDescription) { description.append(chars); }

                 if (inDate && date == null) { date = chars; }

        }

        private class ProcessFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> 
        {       
            @Override
            protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) 
            {
                String url = params[0];

                InputStream inputStream = null;

                try 
                {           
                    inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();

                    reader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream)); 

                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                { 
                    TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
                    titleView.setText(e.toString());
                }

                return inputStream;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) 
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                if (result != null) {
                    ResetDisplay();
                }   
            }
        }

        public void processFeed()
        {
            try 
            {
                SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

                SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

                reader = parser.getXMLReader();
                reader.setContentHandler(this);

                new ProcessFeedTask().execute(url);

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
                titleView.setText(e.toString());
            }
        }

        public String getTitle() { return title ; }
        public String getDate() { return date ; }
        public String getDescription() { return description.toString() ; }
        public Bitmap getImage() { return image ; }
    }
}
```

If you run the code in an emulator, give it a while to work, I think the internet speed of the emulator is rather slow.

Hope that helps somebody out there.

Cheers.

Neill

Answer (score -1):

You have to make following correction in place where you are calling `resetDisplay()` method in your `mainactivity.java`

```
resetDisplay(handler.getTitle(), handler.getDate(), handler.getImage(), handler.getDescription());
```